# Refresh or Reload modal after button click inside modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

On the main page I have a datatable that includes buttons for each row. The button allows users to click and view errors specific to that object on a popup modal. Within the modal I have a button where users can clear the errors. When a user clicks one of the clearing buttons I'm having problems figuring out how to 1) refresh the modal to show the most recent content or 2) re-open the modal.

**Main page button (opens modal):**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewclustererrors" href="./cluster_errors.php?cluster='.urlencode($row2['CLUSTER_NAME']).'" class="btn-sm btn-success"> Errors </a>
```

The main page button opens the modal, sends the `$cluster` varible and loads the content from the `cluster_errors.php` page.

**cluster_errors.php (modal content):**

```
<?php  
if ( !empty($_GET['cluster'])) {
    $cluster = $_GET['cluster'];
}
?>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
    aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
  <?php echo $cluster;?> has errors!</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title" id="clustererrortable">
          <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right">
            <?php echo $cluster;?> error table
          </i>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="cluster_error_table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Occured <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th>Object <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th>Type <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th>Error <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th>Resolution Notes <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th>Resolved <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php                 
             $sql = "<sql query>";
                        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
                        if( $stmt === false) {
                            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
                        }

                        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                        echo'<tr>
                            <td>'.$row['DATE_OCCURED'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['OBJECT_NAME'].'</td>    
                            <td>'.$row['ERROR_TYPE'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['ERROR'].'</td>      
                            <td>'.$row['RESOLUTION_NOTES'].'</td>';
                            echo'
                <td>';
                   if ( $row['RESOLVED'] == 'False') {
                   echo '<a href="./cluster_resolve_error.php?object='.$cluster.'" class="btn-sm btn-warning" style="margin-left: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i> Not Resolved</a>';
                   } else {
                   echo '<a href="#" class="btn-sm btn-success" style="margin-left: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> Resolved</a>';
                   }
                   echo'
                </td>
                </tr>';
                    }
                    ?>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!-- /.table-responsive -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The `cluster_errors.php` modal fetches the `$cluster` variable from the previous button click and queries the database. The results are shown in another datatable in the modal. Buttons are created to clear each of the errors. The clearing buttons reach out to the `cluster_resolve_error.php` script.

**cluster_resolve_error.php (script that clears errors):**

```
<?php 
if ( !empty($_GET['object'])) {
    $object = $_GET['object'];

} 

$sql = "<SQL QUERY>";
                    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
                    if( $stmt === false) {
                        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
                    }
        $object = NULL;

        $url = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        $trimmedHeader = $url['scheme'] . '://' . $url['host'] . $url['path'];
        header('Location: ' . $trimmedHeader . '#' . $tab);

?>
```

Currently if the clearing button is clicked it updates the database and then forwards back to the main page via `header('Location:`. But then that forces the user to click the button on the mainpage to reopen the modal to clear more errors.

How do I refresh or reload the content after the clearing button is clicked and forward the same variables?

Thanks!

Comment: I think Ajax is the solution, you need to fetch the data via Ajax in modal so no need to redirect and no need to reopen the modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ajax to send request to the server when user clicks on `<a href="./cluster_resolve_error.php">` link and then update the "Resolved" column row using the DataTables API method [`cell().data()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/cell%28%29.data%28%29).

For example:

```js
$('#cluster_error_table').on('click', '.btn-warning', function(e){       
   var cell = $(this).closest('td');

   $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(){
      // Update "Resolved" column
      $('#cluster_error_table').DataTable().cell(cell).data(
         '<a href="#" class="btn-sm btn-success" style="margin-left: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> Resolved</a>'
      );
   });

   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have put your code in the cluster_errors.php modal page but when user clicks the button it forwards to cluster_resolve_error.php and displays a blank page. How do I get around this?

Comment: Figured it out. I created a hidden iframe and targeted it so it doesn't refresh. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @solar411, although your workaround worked, it should not follow the link because default action is prevented with `e.preventDefault()`, are you sure you didn't omit anything?

Comment: Yes I copy/pasted directly. The only thing I removed was the `;` from the `style="margin-left: 5px;"` because I was getting a Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL.